# R : randomly divide 10 data values into a group of 5 and a group of 5

Tags: r, list, random, combinations

I would like to find all the possibilities to divide 10 data values into 2 groups of 5
If i'm right there are 252 possibilities 
  choose(10,5)
  252

How can i do it with R ?

Thanks !

Comment: `a <- 0:9; (b <- combn(a, 5)); (c <- apply(b, 2, function(x) a[!a %in% x]))`?

Comment: Yes I saw the combn function in R, but how can i create a vector of length 10 in which each value is present only once ?

Comment: Hm I guess I don't understand. Plz provide an example for your *10 data values* and your *vector of length 10 in which each value is present only once*.

Comment: here is the vector i have :

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility:

```
a <- letters[1:10] 
split1 <- combn(a, 5); 
split2 <- apply(b, 2, function(x) a[!a %in% x])
```

Pick a random one:

```
set.seed(1)
rnd <- sample(1:ncol(split1), size=1)
split1[, rnd]; split2[, rnd]
# [1] "a" "c" "d" "g" "i"
# [1] "b" "e" "f" "h" "j"
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can i create all possible vector of 10 values (252 if i'm right) with your method ?

Comment: @user1845261  `combn` returns **all** combinations of `N choose M` . You complete each "vector of 10" by selecting the remaining elements of `letters[1:10]` which are *not* in each 5-element vector.

Comment: Yes thanks i did : for(i in 1:ncol(split1)){tmp1 <- split1[,i];tmp2 <- setdiff(wt,tmp1); final <- c(tmp1,tmp2); for(j in 1:10) {matrice[i,j] <- final[j]}}

Answer (score 0):

So i will explain in details what i have to do : 
I have 2 sets of data :

```
cellular_wt = c(1.1656,0.9577,1.3655,0.9016,0.9336)
cellular_mutant = c(2.8896,5.7018,3.595,1.6998,1.8893)

secreted_wt = c(7.8491,6.1546,5.1972,6.1607,5.928)
secreted_mutant = c(4.6801,3.2418,3.6651,3.0678,2.3221)

mean_cellular_wt <- mean(cellular_wt)
mean_cellular_mutant <- mean(cellular_mutant)
mean_secreted_wt <- mean(secreted_wt)
mean_secreted_mutant <- mean(secreted_mutant)

mean_secreted_wt/mean_cellular_wt = 5.877085
mean_secreted_mutant/mean_cellular_mutant = 1.076156

mean_ratio <- (mean_secreted_wt/mean_cellular_wt)/(mean_secreted_mutant/mean_cellular_mutant) = 5.46
```

I want to run a randomization test on these data to test the significance of mean ratio

To do so, i would like to randomly divide these 10 values (cellular_wt + cellular_mutant and secreted_wt + secreted_mutant into 2 groups of 5 (as the initial data sets), and calculate the mean ratio each time. 
In this way, i can see whether the observed difference of 5.46 seems unusually large by comparing it to the 252 differences that could have been seen due to random assignment alone. Do you understand ?